# How to compare the contents of files in two different directories using a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I've seen similar questions asked, but usually the response is to use

```
diff -br directory/sub1 directory/sub2
```

I don't want to compare the contents of the two folders, but the contents of a similar file across multiple directories without having to copy the files in each time.

Here's what I'm trying to use:

```
function compare_files() {
        local num=$1
        diff readings.santitized.dat "/../ex"$num"/readings.sanitized.dat"
        diff pressure.delta.log "/../ex"$num"/pressure.delta.txt"
        diff error.log "/../ex"$num"/error.txt"
}
```

The num variable is used because I have several different example folders labeled ex1,ex2,... that contain files with the same names but different contents.

Currently it returns that there is no such directory. I've ran it without the quotations around the path and got the same error.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
Possible solution found. Added absolute path to command.

```
local PATH="/home/..."
diff readings.santitized.dat "$PATH/ex"$num"/readings.sanitized.dat"
...
```

EDIT: 
Note that Fanatique's solution is correct. Use the absolute path. DON'T use all-caps for variable names. That's why my diff command wasn't registering.

Here's the final snippet that works:

```
local path="/home/..."
(diff file.filetype $path/ex"$num"/file.filetype)
...
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser! Have you tried using absolute path instead of relative?

Comment: @Fanatique I've just tried to do that. Now it's saying "diff: command not found". I believe my problem's been fixed, but I'll have to look into that one. May be problematic since I'm on a shared system and I don't believe I can download packages. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the issue might be "/../" instead on just "../"  
"/../" says start at the root directory and go up 1 level.  
"../" says start in the current directory and go up one level.

Comment: If a path starts with "/", that indicates that it's absolute (i.e. starts at the root directory). When using a relative path, you need to leave off the starting "/".